# android how to add items dynamically to a listview like in chat application

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to do a chat application. In my activity I have a `ListView` and at bottom `EditText` with a `Button` "Send"

Like in chat after writing in `EditText` and press the `Send Button` the text will appear in `ListView`. Two users are there.  If the last user is same then that text should add to the previous list.

How can i do that ?
here is my code below,

http://pastebin.com/hghj1fBJ

i don't want in this structure,

me: hi  (after  send button click)

me: h r u (after send button click)

i want in this structure,

its taking two list item but i want

me: hi  (after  send button click)

```
 h r u (after send button click)
```

friend: fine

Comment: use notifyDataSetChanged() for adapter after clicking send button....

Comment: try messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in onclick of button

Comment: what do you mean by previous list?

Comment: like gtalk if last typed message by me: then the next text ll add to same list, still the next user send the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void sendMessage(String message)
    {
        messageAdapter.add("me :"+message);
        messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged used for updating. But here all these things are updating not a problem. my problem is how to add text to previous list if the user is same

Comment: You wrote that you have one listView.So,just add the text like how you added for previous text.or Need more explanation.

Comment: ya there is one listview, i am asking for list item.  lists of messages are there. i want to  add more text to same list item

Comment: when you will call the line "messageAdapter.add("me :"+message);".It will add your message into the adapter.After calling notifyDataSetChanged it will display your message in the listView.So,what is your problem?

Comment: my problem is every message after send button click , its taking  as new list item. for example,                                          me: hi                                                               me:h r u                                                            instead of this i want                                             me:hi                                                                  h r u

Comment: ooh...i got it.Then just read last item from adapter then concate it with your current text.Then remove last item and add the new text.Hope this will sovle ur problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to build chat kind of application, you should check transcript mode of listview too. 
check here,
http://www.mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/listview-transcript-mode

Comment: which example u gave i am also getting same output in my code. But my question is different  , how to add text to last list. like gtalk if lass typed message by me: then the next text ll add to same list

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you call notifyDataSetChanged() on your ArrayAdapter.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged used for updating. But here all these things are updating not a problem. my problem is how to add text to previous list if the user is same

Comment: @Jyosna : I see you use only adapter, but did you make your onw adapter? I guess here you would have to create an array of chat data. One instance would hold a username, message and time stamp for example. Then, create your custom adapter to handle the array of chat data and create functions for adding a new instance of chat data when user presses enter or presses a button send. After that you invalidate so adapter can reread data in the chatdata array and display it.

Answer (score 0):

**setAdpater()**.. method should be called after the new text is beeing added.. and the String[] array should be updated with new values..
or

refer this http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List12.html

Comment: which example u gave i am also getting same output in my code. But my question is different , how to add text to last list. like gtalk if lass typed message by me: then the next text ll add to same list

Comment: @Jyosna.. make sure to add the recent message to the String[] array. and then take new ArrayAdapter() using this String[] array and then setAdapter. and make sure to that String[] array holds all old and new values.

Comment: i am using custom adapter for that. for testing purpose i gave arrayadapter

Comment: @Jyosna.. Even in CustomAdapter you will use String[] array some where, so Update it...

Comment: no i am using a class with in that setter and getter methods are there not the String[]

Comment: @Jyosna.. ya... either you can make some changes to update new values or work some other way around...